Junit 5 tests are not getting discovered
I am using Springboot version 2.4.13 and below JUnit 5 dependencies:

junit-jupiter-api 5.7.2
junit-bom 5.7.2
junit-platform-suite-api 1.8.0
junit-platform-suite 1.8.0

I am using below Test suite:
package org.onap.so;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ExcludeTags;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeClassNamePatterns;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

@Suite
@ExcludeTags("spring-aware")
@IncludeClassNamePatterns(".*Test")
@SelectPackages("org.onap.so")
public class NonSpringSuite {
}

Plugin configuration:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/**NonSpringSuite.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

But all my JUnit 5 tests are not getting discovered.
I tried some solutions but nothing works.
Error:
WARNING: Third-party TestEngine implementations are forbidden to use the reserved 'junit-' prefix for their ID: 'junit-platform-suite'
[ERROR] TestEngine with ID 'junit-platform-suite' failed to discover tests


I haven't done anything with Spring Boot for quite some time now, but why aren't you using the Spring Boot BOM? v2.4.13 comes with the JUnit BOM v5.7.2. And if you would be able to use the Spring Parent POM, you would also get plugin management.

@beatngu13 Tried that too, still test not getting discovered

Then I'm afraid I / the community can't help without an MRE.
